# Using external composite jQuery Templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I wanted to try out jQuery Templates after being inspired by these 2 blog postings

- http://encosia.com/2010/11/10/composition-with-jquery-templates-why-and-how/
- http://encosia.com/2010/10/05/using-external-templates-with-jquery-templates/

Well, it's not quite working for me.  If I have the template code on the page itself it works fine, but loading remotely isn't working for me.  It appears the template is being retrieved ok. what is wrong here?

External template:

```
<script id="contactsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <table class="contacts">
    <thead><tr><td class="ui-helper-hidden">Id</td><td>Name</td><td>City</td><td>State</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    {{each contact}}
        {{tmpl($value) '#contactTemplate'}}
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<script id="contactTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr><td class="ui-helper-hidden">${id}</td><td>${name}</td><td>${city}</td><td>${state}</td></tr>
</script>
```

On my page I'm using this code to retrieve and load the template:

```
var contacts = {
    contact: [
        { id: 1, name: "John Green", city: "Orange Beach", state: "AL" },
        { id: 2, name: "Sam Thompson", city: "Pensacola", state: "FL" },
        { id: 3, name: "Mary Stein", city: "Mobile", state: "AL" }
    ]
};

$("#ShowDataRemote").button().click(function() {
    $.get('templates/Contact.htm', function(template) {
        alert(template);
        $.tmpl(template, contacts).appendTo("body");
        alert("async done");
    });
});
```

---

### Update:

A new blog post on Encosia explains this question and answer...

http://encosia.com/2010/12/02/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That simple remote loading technique won't work with composite templates, since the string you're loading isn't a valid template itself.  You can get it working by changing your click handler like this:

```
$("#ShowDataRemote").button().click(function() {
  $.get('templates/Contact.htm', function(template) {
    // Inject the template script blocks into the page.
    $('body').append(template);

    // Use those templates to render the data.
    $('#contactsTemplate').tmpl(contacts).appendTo("body");
  });
});
```

Comment: Why is the template invalid when retrieved by $.get(), but works fine locally?

Comment: Because it's two separate templates, including the non-template x-jquery-tmpl script markup. The .tmpl(template, data) usage is only appropriate when you're feeding it a template string and nothing more.

Comment: I know I tried this workaround, but it didn't work for me.  I must have had something wrong because it works now.  Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a new post specifically about this combination, if you're interested: http://encosia.com/2010/12/02/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/

Comment: I know.  I guess you missed it, but I updated the question with a link to your new post on this.  Thanks for the article!

Answer (score 0):

You can compile template string as a "named template", like this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366280/1274343