# Best way to separate C# and HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, structure

I've been working with a team on a ASP.NET project, a project management tool.
Most of the pages is basically writing stuff from the database to the page and store the changes which where made.

This is our first project in ASP.NET (We currently use ASP Classic for all our other projects), our senior told us not to use MVC.

The problem now is that our Designer/Front-end developer is pretty much clueless if it comes to ASP.NET, he also does not want to use VisualStudio if possible (He uses OSX).

For example:
What would for example be the best way to write a dynamic list?

This is what we currently do:

```
<div id="tasks" overflow-y="scroll" style="height:400px;">
   <ul id='taskList'>
     <% PrintTasks(); %>
   </ul>
</div>
```

In the code-behind:

```
public void PrintTasks()
{
        foreach (var task in _tasks)
        {
            Response.Write("<li rel='#' id='task_"+task.TaskID+"'>" +
                   ...
                "</span>" +
                "</li>");
        } 
}
```

In this case, its not possible for the designer to edit the li tags without going into the code behind.

Thanks.

Comment: Writing ASP.NET web apps...not being allowed to use MVC and having the requirement to be able to code on OSX...That seems a very useful combination.....

Comment: The best way is use ASP.NET MVC, your senior is wrong. The problem of ASP.NET preciselly is the mixing of HTML and logic.

Comment: `our senior told us not to use MVC`. Shame. MVC is a lot more natural than WebForms for developers coming from classic ASP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the specific case you mentionned, in 'classical' asp.net, you're supposed to use a repeater: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.80).aspx

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">                       
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li rel='#' id='task_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TaskID") %>'>
            <span>Whatever</span>
        </li>
      </ItemTemplate>            
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Basically, learn which webcontrols are available, create new ones every time it's necessary, and try to get as much as you can from asp.net webform's limited binding/templating system.

Comment: I'm going to propose MVC, but this answer does fix the issue for now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your front-end developer will have to suck it up and learn how to use VS. If your entire team is working on ASP.Net, there is no way to escape the wrath of VS.

MVC is a good for separation of C# and HTML. Razor engine allows a nice way to separate code and markup.

For you list you would probably do something like that in Razor:

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
    <li rel="#" id ="blah_@item.id">@item.text</li>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should absolutely raise the question why MVC is not an option. It would be a much better fit for what you're doing, and the code quality would therefore also be much better, which helps the project overall. Not to speak of team productivity (and the ability for your designer to "escape" VS).

Doing some CSHTML with Razor you and your team would almost feel "at home".

Answer (score 1):

According to your context, the main friction point is your front end developper.

So, decide on using a javascript framework (Knockout.js, angular.js, whatever). 
Let your front-end developer design the UI that will get all needed info from JSON provided by your web stack of choice (ASP.NET MVC, Web Api, whatever).
This will ensure that he can develop his UI with the tool he wants. And you can work on the backend without worrying about UI. You just need to agree on the JSON contracts and stick to them.

This way, you will keep a clean separation of concerns with : 
- everyone developping with the tools they're most at ease with
- no layer mix and match (ie having some HTML "generated" in your code behind)

And, your list will look like (using knockout) (syntax may not be accurate):

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myList">
    <li><span data-bind="text: Text, attr: { id: Id }" /></li>
</ul>
```

Code behind (using asp.net mvc) (syntax may not be accurate)

```
public JsonResult GetList()
{
    var res =  myServiceLayer
        .GetListItems()
        .Select( 
            x => new { Text = x.Val, Id = x.Id } 
        );
    return JsonResult( res );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using ASP.NET WebForms, I would give you the following suggestions:

1. Take advantage of CSS. Accept that your designer will not be able to edit the HTML produced by your code-behind, but if you use CSS intelligently you can probably overcome that challenge. In your example, you have a `div` and a `ul` element with id's, and the designer can then change the CSS to style these elements and child elements using the cascading properties of CSS. (Ex: `#taskList > li`)
2. Consider client side templating when appropriate. When presenting data for the user, fx. lists, consider using a templating framework. (jQuery fx) These templates can be placed in separate files that your designer can edit without VS. (Reference: [load jQuery-Templates from external file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366137/load-jquery-templates-from-external-file))
3. Spend some time learning the different controls available in ASP.NET WebForms, instead of using `Response.Write` to build HTML. Using `Response.Write` in the code-behind is generally a really bad practice and should be avoided, because your code will quickly turn into spaghetti and be unmaintainable. And if you're hoping to use ASP.NET WebForms (Or MVC) on later projects and want your senior and management to see the advantages of ASP.NET, then you and your team should spend a little time learning the framework. When you do that, you will be rewarded with more structured code that is easier to maintain. But if you use your current Classic ASP practices in ASP.NET, chances are that neither your senior or your management will see the benefits of using ASP.NET. And that would be a shame, because the benefits are really there. :-)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use Repeater here:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="r1">
<ItemTemplate>
  <li rel='#' id='<%# Eval("id","prefix{0}") %>'><span>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="t1"><%# Eval("Caption") %></asp:Label>
  </span></li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in cs file:

```
r1.DataSource=list;
r1.DataBind();
```