# What is the good way of writing tons of HTML code with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing several HTML forms dynamically with jQuery inside a Django project. This is how I do it right now:

```js
function WriteSomeRandomContent() {
    var sContent = "<h3>foobar</h3>";
    sContent += "<br />";
    sContent += "<p>Gosh ! This is a lot of HTML content !</p>";
    ...
    sContent += "<p>For real dude I have to do it within decades of lines !</p>";
    $("#foobar").html(sContent);
}
```

What I want to do is removing the ugly HTML code from my JavaScript function by using some sort of HTML templates which I could then *include* in my `sContent` variable.

Is there any way to do this, or is there an even better way to handle big amounts of HTML code within JavaScript ?

## Edit

---

Possible duplicate: [load jQuery-Templates from external file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4366137/1824222)

Comment: the good way is not doing this.

Comment: Why would you need to handle big amount of HTML code within javascript? Can't you edit the server's output?

Comment: You could use AJAX to retrieve the template from your server, and place it in a string, then do your variable replacement. The best way to handle adding large amounts of HTML to an existing page is through one giant string it seems, rather than adding each node individuality.

Comment: @RobinCastlin I am porting a desktop application, it has several menu buttons which write corresponding content into, say, `#content-right`. So I need to call a given JavaScript function which will fill my `<div>` accordingly.

Comment: read this one http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dust.js, Handlebars.js, jquery templates... and many other similar thing..

Google them..

Comment: From what I searched and found, the plugins looked too powerful to me for what I want to achieve. Looking into Handlebars.js at the moment. Also, can I use the `{{ }}` Handlebars notation inside a Django project ? Edit: Yes, using `{% verbatim %}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript templating. Something like AngularJS, Ember.

Comment: angularjs is great for templating.

Answer (score 0):

yeah definitely use some sort of templating like underscore.js offers a method called template

```
<script id="listItem" type="text/template">
    <h3>{{ dynamic_text }}</h3>";
     <br />
    <p>Gosh ! This is a lot of HTML content !</p>
    <p>For real dude I have to do it within decades of lines !</p>
</script>
```

Then using something like backbone.js along with underscore you can do this.

```
App.Views.ListItem = Backbone.View.extend({
   tagName: 'li',
   template: _.template($('#listItem')),
   render: function(){
      //binds the model data to our template and then appends it to our view (ex: li )
      this.$el.append( this.template( this.model.toJSON ) );
      return this;
   }
});
```

You can also add a template helper method to make things more simple by doing this

```
window.template = function(id){
   return _.template($('#' + id));
}
//template: template('listItem')
```