# Hide the template code

Tags: javascript, jquery-templates

i'am working on a little javascript library, that uses the lovely jquery-tmpl engine. I would like to avoid forcing the user to paste the necessary templates into his/her html (or to be confronted with the template code at all for that matter).
So my question is: Is there a way to hide my template code, preferably in my js file, as I understand, the script-tags are necessary (if only in order to be able to select it with jquery).
The only thing I found so far is putting the templates in external file like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315679/using-external-composite-jquery-templates) but it is not really what i want.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.template('yourTemplateName', 'yourTemplateCode');
```

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

> This method compiles the markup in the template parameter as a named template, which can be referenced using the string specified in the name parameter.
>
> The return value is the compiled-template function.
>
> Example: Create a compiled template associated with the name "summaryTemplate" and then reference it by name for rendering:

```
// Convert the markup string into a named template
$.template( "summaryTemplate", "<li>${Name}</li>" );

function renderList() {
    // Render the movies data using the named template: "summaryTemplate"
    $.tmpl( "summaryTemplate", movies ).appendTo( "#moviesList" );
}
```